# Dualizing Intersections to unions in the subobject poset

Tags: category-theory

I'm sorry for the very silly doubt.

Recall that if we have two subobjects $[h_1],[h_2]$ of a given object $C$, their intersection $[h]$ has the following properties:

1. $h=h_1 \circ t_1=h_2 \circ t_2$ for some $t_1,t_2$;
2. if $f: A \to C$ has the property that $f=h_1 \circ s_1=h_2 \circ s_2$, then there exists a morphism $s$ for which $f=h \circ s$.

I want to dualize 1)-2) in order two get the union of two subobjects. In such a case, I get

1d) $h \circ t'_1=h_1$ and $h \circ t'_2=h_2$ for some $t'_1,t'_2$;

2d) if $f: C \to A$ has the property that $f \circ s'_1=h_1$ and $f \circ s'_2=h_2$, then there exists a morphism $s$ for which $f \circ s=h$.

Is property $2d)$ correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is alot of context missing, but still I think your 2d is not correct. It seems to me that it does not provide the right universal property for the union of subobjects. In fact, I don't understand how $f\circ s_1' = h_1$ is even supposed to work, since $f$ has codomain $A$, while $h_1$ has codomain $C$ (I read it as one of the inclusions representing the subobject $[h_1]$...).

The right way to phrase the intersection and union of subobjects is by saying that they are the *meet* and *join* in the subobject lattice. In the case of the intersection you can also say that the intersection is obtained as the pullback
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
A_1\cap A_2 & \overset{t_1}\rightarrow & A_1\\
{}_{t_2}\downarrow\;\;&&\;\;\;\downarrow_{h_1}\\
A_2&\underset{h_2}\rightarrow&C
\end{array}$$
in your category. For the union one might be tempted to consider the pushout
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
A_1\cap A_2 & \overset{t_1}\rightarrow & A_1\\
{}_{t_2}\downarrow\;\;&&\downarrow\\
A_2 &\rightarrow& A_1\cup A_2
\end{array}$$
and indeed you will obtain a map $A_1\cup A_2 \rightarrow C$ from the universal property of a pushout. However it is not clear (and false for a generic category) that this morphism is monic and exhibits $A_1\cup A_2$ as a subobject of $C$. This condition is necessary and sufficient to be able to describe the union of subobjects as a pushout.

Long story short: the union of subobjects is formally dual if constructed via its universal property in the subobject lattice. It is **not** formally dual, when constructing it inside the ambient category.

Comment: Thus, I cannot use a property which corrects 2d), right?

Comment: You can. The correction of 2d is the pushout + induced monic property in my answer.